# Probability of uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let X be a standard uniformly distributed random variable X.

I try to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \in [0,\frac{1}{2}[)$

What I did:

I know that $\mathbb{P}(X \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]) = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-0} dy = \frac{1}{2}$

$\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure so by $\sigma$-additivity:
$\mathbb{P}(X \in [0,\frac{1}{2}[) = \mathbb{P}(X \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]) -\mathbb{P}(X = \frac{1}{2}) $

But how to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X = \frac{1}{2})$ ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard uniform distribution](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/Standarduniform.pdf) is continuous, and it has no singletons with positive probability.
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X = \frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you. is it because $\mathbb{P}(X=a)=\int_a^a \frac{1}{1-0}dy = 0$?

Comment: @PerelMan Yes, you can do so.